# User with root privileges to restart a service can't

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I want a user to be able to restart the php5-fpm service.  In visudo, I have the following:

`username ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/php5-fpm`

When I `su` to the user and run `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop`, nothing happens.  There's no feedback and the service is still running.

What do I need to do to allow `username` to control the service?  Running Ubuntu 13.10.

Edit: Looking in `auth.log` I see

```
sudo: username : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rootslash's comments suggest, I believe something in the PHP-FPM binary needs root that this user doesn't have (opening ports maybe?).  I've decided to have this user touch a file that the root user checks once a minute (cron) and if it's found, restarts the service and then deletes the file.

Not ideal, but works to make this happen.

Answer (score -1):

Can you modify as below in *visudo*?

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop

username ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/php5-fpm stop, /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
```

Comment: Tried, still not able to stop the service.

Comment: 1. as root, if you do that is it working fine?

Comment: Yes.  If I'm root, I can start and stop the service.

Comment: what is the permission of /etc/init.d/php5-fpm

Comment: It's owned by root and the group is root.  Permissions are 755.

Comment: Is there any other way to start/stop the php5-fpm instead of using under init.d? If yes, can you try to add that and try?

Comment: That's kind of the point of using services under /etc/init.d.

Comment: @tubaguy50035: Make sure there is nothing that script that checks for root

Comment: @0A0D I don't think so.  If I add the user to the sudo group, it works.  Just not when I specifically allow this one command.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have SELinux or one of the other security managers running?  If so, even though the command runs as root the user might still have their security tag and not have access to execute files in /etc.

You could temporarily disable SELinux and test if the command starts working.  For SELinux, I believe you can use the "setenforce" command to temporarily disable it.

Comment: I do not have SELinux running.

Comment: This is a generic ubuntu server install.  I've done very little configuration other than adding a user and installing php.

Comment: According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor, AppArmor is turned on by default in Ubuntu 7.10 and higher.  Maybe it can cause the same kind of problem as SELinux?  I don't know anything about AppArmor, though.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried sudo service php5-fpm stop/start?
if that works just add user  ALL: NOPASSWD: /sbin/service
to the /etc/sudoers file

Comment: If I add the user to the sudo group, it can do that.  But I only want the user to be able to start and stop the php service, not all services.

Comment: add , /usr/sbin/php5-fpm to the sudoers line as below and see if that corrects.

Comment: /usr/sbin/php5-fpm is a completely different script...

Comment: its the primary daemon for the init.d script the thingy that it starts and stops and apparmor might be being picky about allowing ONLY the run of the /etc/init.d/php5-fpm and not allowing it to spawn to run the actual binary was my point.

Comment: AppArmor does not seem to be a problem here.  Wouldn't I see something in syslog?  I don't see anything there when running the command.

Comment: It would actually be in the auth OR the php5-fpm logging if anywhere.

Comment: Nothing in the php5-fpm log.  The auth log shows what I posted in the question.

Comment: actually try this in the sudoers file
user ALL: NOPASSWORD:/sbin/service php5-fpm
and see if "that" works
or try
user ALL: NOPASSWORD:/etc/init.d/php5-fpm, /usr/sbin/php5-fpm, /etc/php5/fpm/, /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
i suspect that because it's running it as a php daemon instead of an actual service daemon it may need the full access to the files.

Comment: I added all the files to my line in visudo, still nothing.  I see what you're getting at now, I have no idea how to find all the files it would need access to.

Comment: it should all be contained in the init.d script of what you need, the only one that i can think of is the actual php5 binary  i remember having this issue with kibana/elastic search because it was invoking java as the binary not the .jar file that it claimed was the "daemon"
the service php5-fpm "should" work the best out of the lot because of how service functions vs just an init script.